# Julia - fixed size array in C struct

Tags: c, struct, julia

I need to make a Julia type corresponding to a C struct that has a fixed size array:

```
struct cstruct {
    ...
    int arr[N] //N known at compile time
    ...
};
```

I have defined Julia types corresponding to other C structs with arrays like this:

```
type  jstruct
    ...
    arr::Ptr{Cint}
    ...
end
```

But as I understand it, this only works when `arr`  is a pointer, not an array of a specific size.  How can I ensure that the offsets of elements coming after `arr` remain the same in both languages?

Comment: Structs can contain array members. It's just more common to use pointers to avoid copying the values when passing the struct as an argument (C passes by value...). Just use a pointer, and create a custom initialization function that will `malloc(N * sizeof *struct_var->arr);` instead

Comment: That is what I would do if cstruct were not already defined with `int arr[N]` in the library I'm using.  What I need is a way to define a compatible type in Julia, so that I can `ccall` a function that returns a `cstruct*` and `unsafe_load` it to get a `jstruct`.  If the offsets are not the same then this will segfault.

Comment: Create your own bindings, and `memcpy` the array onto a pointer, or simply create a dummy struct where `dummy.arr = &cstruct_var.arr[0];`, although that's slightly risky because the library might change/deallocate the memory at any point

Comment: If I make a dummy struct with `dummy.arr = &cstruct_var.arr[0];` then the offsets of every member after `arr` will be changed by `sizeof(int*)` rather than `N*sizeof(int)`, correct?  I tested both solutions and they resulted in segfaults as well.  All I need is a way to tell Julia that the member following `arr` is `N*sizeof(Cint)` bytes past `arr` so that I can convert the structs returned by C functions to the Julia type and use the Julia type as an argument to C functions.  If the offsets don't line up exactly then this won't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you define a C struct with a fixed size array (or with the array hack), the data are stored directly inline within that struct.  It's not a pointer to another region.  The equivalent Julia structure is:

```
type JStruct{N}
    arr::NTuple{N,Int}
end
```

That will store the integers directly inline within the struct.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you want array-type operations on this object in Julia, the [StaticArrays](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl) package might be useful. It uses tuples to store the elements of arrays, while also giving them an AbstractArray interface.